# Select paragraph and apply style in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

When selecting a whole paragraph using triple click or shift and cursor key past the end of the paragraph, if I apply a block style to the selection (for example a heading or block quote) the style is also applied to the next paragraph.

Is there a way of avoiding this and applying the style only to the selection?

For example:

[image: Selecting a line with triple click (in blue) and applying a style]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug (or peculiarity) of CKEditor. The problem is that the range object ends at the element following the selection

```
<p>...</p> {[<p>text</p>] <p>}...</p>    # [] - selection, {} - range
```

The end of the range needs to be moved:

```
<p>...</p> {[<p>text</p>]} <p>...</p>
```

I use a custom-made toolbar, so I apply all block formats with a code like this:

```
style = new CKEDITOR.style element: 'h1'
range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0]
if not range.collapsed and range.endOffset is 0 and range.endContainer instanceof CKEDITOR.dom.element
  range.setEndAfter range.endContainer.getPrevious()

style.applyToRange range, editor
```